# Not sure where and how to add a simple modal using Angular JS, Bootstrap and ASP NET 5

Tags: html, asp.net, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

I am building a small sample app using Angular JS and ASP NET 5. The format of my application is as follows:

Under the `wwwroot` folder I have  a `css, Partials and Views` folder there is also a `App.js` that is minified using uglify (using task manager to automatically minify stuff with grunt).

```
Views
   add.html
   delete.html
   edit.html
   list.html
Index.html  (at the root level)
```

Outside of the `wwwroot` folder I have a `Scripts` folder, in this folder I have sub folders:

```
 Controllers
     orgController.js
 Services
     orgService.js
 App.js
```

**The App.js file looks like this:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];

    var orgApp = angular.module('orgApp', [
        'ngRoute', 'orgServices'
    ]).config(config);

    function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/Views/list.html',
                controller: 'OrgListController'
            })
            .when('/organizations/add', {
                templateUrl: '/Views/add.html',
                controller: 'OrgAddController'
            })
            .when('/organizations/edit/:id', {
                templateUrl: '/Views/edit.html',
                controller: 'OrgEditController'
            })
            .when('/organizations/delete/:id', {
                templateUrl: '/Views/delete.html',
                controller: 'OrgDeleteController'
            });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode
            ({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: false
            });
    }
})();
```

**Then in the `orgController.js` I have:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('orgApp')
        .controller('OrgListController', OrgListController)
        .controller('OrgAddController', OrgAddController)
        .controller('OrgEditController', OrgEditController)
        .controller('OrgDeleteController', OrgDeleteController)
        .controller('DatePickerController', DatePickerController);

    /* Organizations List Controller  */
    OrgListController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Organization'];

    function OrgListController($scope, Organization) {
        $scope.organizations = Organization.query();
        $scope.showModal = function () {
            $scope.showModal = true;
        }
    }

    /* Organizations Create Controller */
    OrgAddController.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', 'Organization'];

    function OrgAddController($scope, $location, Organization) {
        $scope.organization = new Organization();
        $scope.add = function () {
            $scope.organization.$save(
                // success
                function () {
                    $location.path('/');
                },
                // error
                function (error) {
                    _showValidationErrors($scope, error);
                });
        };
    }

    /* Organizations Edit Controller */
    OrgEditController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Organization'];

    function OrgEditController($scope, $routeParams, $location, Organization) {
        $scope.organization = Organization.get({ id: $routeParams.id });
        $scope.edit = function () {
            $scope.organization.$save(// success
                function () {
                    $location.path('/');
                },
                // error
                function (error) {
                    _showValidationErrors($scope, error);
                });
        };
    }

    /* Organizations Delete Controller  */
    OrgDeleteController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Organization'];

    function OrgController($scope, $routeParams, $location, Organization) {
        $scope.organization = Organization.get({ id: $routeParams.id });
        $scope.remove = function () {
            $scope.organization.$remove({ id: $scope.organization.Id }, function () {
                $location.path('/');
            });
        };
    }

    DatePickerController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function DatePickerController($scope) {
        $scope.open = function ($event) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();

            $scope.opened = true;
        };
    }



    /* Utility Functions */

    function _showValidationErrors($scope, error) {
        $scope.validationErrors = [];
        if (error.data && angular.isObject(error.data)) {
            for (var key in error.data) {
                $scope.validationErrors.push(error.data[key][0]);
            }
        } else {
            $scope.validationErrors.push('Could not add organization.');
        };
    }
})();
```

**Finally in the `orgService.js` I have:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('orgServices', ['ngResource'])
        .factory('Organization', Organization);

    Organization.$inject = ['$resource'];

    function Organization($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/organizations/:id');
    }
})();
```

So all I am trying to do is add a modal when a link is clicked on `list.html`, but I am not sure how to do this using Angular JS (jquery is easy), I tried adding a new module with a directive and controller to show the modal but it gave me errors so i deleted it, then i also tried the plunker here http://jsfiddle.net/alexsuch/RLQhh/ as an example provided by some one.. but i was not sure where to place it, if under the orgApp module?.. It was not working so i gave up and thought to drop a line here to get some direction.

**PS:** I am using bootstrap for this app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the Angular UI Bootstrap project. It's a collection of angular directives for the most commonly used Bootstrap components - including the Modal box. That way you wont have to bother with creating your own directives.

This is the link to their documentation: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

---

I've included a short example with some of the more "heavy" steps involved with creating a modal using Angular UI Bootstrap. It isn't too bad and you have a lot of flexibility.

You'll need a template for the modal:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModal.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Hello, Modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{someMessage}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

And a controller:

```
angular.module('orgApp')
.controller('MyModalCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {

    $scope.someMessage = 'This is my modal';

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.close();
    };
});
```

Then when you want to open a modal, you do this from your controllers:

```
OrgListController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Organization', '$uibModal'];

function OrgListController($scope, Organization, $uibModal) {
    $scope.organizations = Organization.query();
    $scope.showModal = function () {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
           templateUrl: 'myModal.html',
           controller: 'MyModalCtrl',
           size: 'sm'
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function () {
           console.log('Modal closed');
        }, function () {
           console.log('Modal dismissed');
        });
    }
}
```

You should read the documentation for a more fulfilling example, such as how to inject data into the modal controller and return results to the calling controller, but this is about it.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS alone doesn't have dialogs, see documentation on [AngularJS API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api)

To create a dialog using AngularJS you would need either Angular-Material or Bootstrap. Both of these have different methods of creating and controlling dialogs with Angular-Material being a bit more powerful in the AngularJS world as with a Material dialog you have the ability to specify the controller for your dialog. [See Angular-Material API](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog)

I also think there are some variation differences when using MVC and Microsoft in how this all interrelates.

Comment: Thank you aallord, i am currently using bootstrap on this application I forgot to comment on that, so I would like to know how i could implement the bootstrap modal using angular so to keep it consistent.

Comment: The AngularJS API is a good place to start. You would create your Bootstrap modal, add "ng-click='function()'" to link tag. Create the function in what controller you want to pen it from and open it using $('#dialogID').modal('show')... Using $('#dialogID').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){ }) allows you to anything needed once the form is displayed.